# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to launch Chrome(Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)) using selenium (2.53.1) with pom as

```html
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
   <version>2.53.1</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
    </dependency>`
```

CODE ::

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

I am getting the following exception in my eclipse console

> D:\eclipse\QA_Code_Git_Gerrit\TA-PAY\api-automation\lib\chromedriver.exe
>   Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461591
>   (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233) on port 38042 Only local
>   connections are allowed. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable   (Driver
>   info: chromedriver=2.29.461591
>   (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT
>       6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 62.38 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision:
>   'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30
>   19:26:09'

Please help me with this. I dont know what is the issue.

Comment: which version of `Chrome Browser` are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: okay. what about Chrome Driver, which version are you using?

Comment: How will I come to know the driver version?

Comment: from where did you download it, it should be available there?

Comment: @AbhishekGarg Any specific reason for this: <exclusion>
     <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    </exclusion>

Comment: @DebanjanB - I added this so as to resolve the YAML file dependency class

Comment: @Jobin - Chrome driver version is 2.29, downloaded from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong version of Chrome Driver.

Since your `Chrome browser` version is `58.0.3029.110`, you have to use `ChromeDriver 2.29`, which can be downloaded from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Comment: I am using the version 2.29 of chrome driver downloaded from chrome driver website

Comment: Oh.. I see looks weird, can you try `2.28` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Selenium 2.53 would work with the latest ChromeDriver. It would be good if you can try with the latest version of Selenium (v 3.4)

Answer (score 0):

Give this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(desiredCapabilities);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: I tried the code, still gives me
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 62.77 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision:

Comment: Now you need to update Selenium Driver to 3 ( not more that )